# How to convert htaccess to nginx rewrite on Centos?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, centos

I have basic htacces in below on Wordpress CMS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How I convert to nginx config with the right way?

Thanks
User Jan

Comment: There are multiple link availables, try this link https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: Thank Ash Patel, I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress
for eg:

```
location /www/ {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/www/(.*)$ /www/www/index.php break;
}
}
```

Comment: if that's helpful then can tick as answer.

Comment: Thank you, I using your guide and it work good with my blog at http://www.wpviet.info